# How to extract string two, one in between brackets and two not in brackets?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out a way to use regular expressions to extract a string into two values. An example string is
"Regional Store 1 - Madison [RSM1]"
"Regional Store 2 [SS2]"

and I would like to have them extracted to "Regional Store 1 - Madison", "RSM1" and "Regional Store 2", "SS2".

I've tried using the regular expression (?<=[)(.*?)(?=]) but it gives me "Regional Store 2 [", "SS2", "]". Other regular expressions I've tried give me "Regional Store 2", "[SS2]".

Since the strings will always follow the format of "{Name} [{code}]" I'm wondering if I should just be using string.split instead.

Comment: [`s.TrimEnd(']').Split(" ["))`](https://ideone.com/CjZaMr)?

Comment: So is `"Regional Store 1 - Madison [RSM1]" "Regional Store 2 [SS2]"` one whole string or did you mean to write it as 2 separate strings? Are the double quotes part of the string?

Comment: I think `string[] parts = myFullString.Split(new char[] { '[',']'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`should do the trick without using TrimEnd if the {Name} part cannot contain either "[" or "]". If it can contain these chars as well, I would go for `int indx = myFullString.LastIndexOf('['); string Name = myFullString.Substring(0, indx); string Code = myFullString.Substring(indx + 1, myFullString.Length - indx - 2);`

Comment: If there is only one line of the specified format each time then you can use this:  var matches = Regex.Matches("Regional Store 1 - Madison [RSM1]", "([^\\[\\]]+)\w").ToArray(); var result = $"{matches[0].Value}={matches[1].Value}";

Answer (score 1):

You may solve the problem without regex by trimming off the trailing `]` and splitting with `"["` or `" ["`:

```cs
var s = "Regional Store 1 - Madison [RSM1]";
var chunks = s.TrimEnd(']').Split(" [");
Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Code={1}", chunks[0], chunks[1]);
// => Name=Regional Store 1 - Madison, Code=RSM1
```

Or, with a regex:

```cs
var pattern = @"^(.*?)\s*\[([^][]*)]$";
chunks = Regex.Match(s, pattern)?.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Code={1}", chunks[0], chunks[1]);
// => Name=Regional Store 1 - Madison, Code=RSM1
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/PNv4rY) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28.*%3F%29%5Cs*%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%29%5D%5Cr%3F%24&i=Regional%20Store%201%20-%20Madison%20%5BRSM1%5D%0D%0ARegional%20Store%202%20%5BSS2%5D&o=m).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\[` -  a `[` char
- `([^][]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]$` - a `]` char and end of string.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a preference between using regex versus string split?

Comment: @redcabbage It is always like that: prefer regex if your string format is known, but it may differ every time, like there may be a different amount of whitespace between some parts, or if numbers are different, or there can be some redundant repetitive parts, etc. Use regular `String.Split` with `String.TrimEnd` if the format is fixed and the strings are always like this, "tidy".

Answer (score 0):

please try this pattern

```
MatchCollection mcCollection = Regex.Matches(sIdentifire, @"(Regional\s+Store\s+.+?\[.+?\])");
```